# Mind maps in Latex?

Tags: diagrams, mindmaps

I would like to dump some minds map in latex. I have them following this structure:

[image: http://www.wikilearning.com/imagescc/sinop2.jpg]

Although it does not need need to be exactly like in that chart, just some nice way of drawing hierarchical outline summaries.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hack your way out using nested `\left\{` delimiters and `tabular` environments. This is a first approximation on which one could improve further.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{subgroup}
  {$\left\{\tabular{l}}
  {\endtabular\right.$}

\begin{document}

Idea General
\begin{subgroup}
  Idea Principal
  \begin{subgroup}
    Ideas Complementarias \\
    Ideas Complementarias \\
    Ideas Complementarias  
  \end{subgroup} \\[2em]
  Idea Principal
  \begin{subgroup}
    Ideas Complementarias \\
    Ideas Complementarias \\
    Ideas Complementarias  
  \end{subgroup} \\[2em]
  Idea Principal
  \begin{subgroup}
    Ideas Complementarias \\
    Ideas Complementarias \\
    Ideas Complementarias  
  \end{subgroup}
\end{subgroup}

\end{document}
```

I have some improvements in mind (but no time to implement them right now): one would like each “entry” in the map to be typeset on a `\parbox` with a `\raggedright` and a specific width. One would also probably want appropriate spacings (such as `\\[2em]`) to be automatically added. Finally one would probably like an user interface closer to `enumerate` and `\item`'s instead of ending entries by `\\`.

I wonder if a package to do exactly this has been already implemented?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. I will try to look at your improvement suggestions too!

Comment: Very nice.  A matter of taste, but I was able to add zome vertical spacing by putting \vspace(xx) directly before and/or after the \\[2em].

Answer (score 25):

See TikZ manual **38 Mindmap Drawing Library**

[image: tikz mind map]

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work. I want to include mostly text.

Comment: That's just an example from the manual. The lib is more flexible. Check out the nicely-cross-referenced manual. For example, the `child` facilities.

Comment: That map is so good. Would be possible to have them in a ConText document?

Comment: @Tomas: TikZ supports plain TeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt, so there should be no problem.

Comment: With TikZ it often seems that [the devteam thinks of everything](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDevTeamThinksOfEverything)…

Comment: Basic code example with different structures of units would be much more useful than a simple screenshot. I feel this answer a stub. - - I think one good example here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7520/13173

Answer (score 6):

this solution with tikz trees might be helpful

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork right,grow=right,level distance=3cm,level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
\node[text width=1cm] {Idea General}
child {node {Some idea}}
child {node {Some idea}
child {node {Details}}
child {node {Details}}
child {node {Details}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nobody seems yet to have mentioned that there is a package to draw precisely this kind of diagram, `schemata`. This may well be because people at the time this question was asked lacked time machines or, therefore, access to future packages. Some people just give up too easily ...

Since no code was provided and I don't know the relevant language, I've translated what I think it may be saying into something more familiar. Well, more familiar to me. Your kilometres, gentle reader, may vary ....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemata}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[welsh]{babel}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{berenis}
\begin{document}
\schema{%
  \schemabox{Syniad Cyffredinol}
}{%
  \schemabox{%
    \schema{%
      \schemabox{Syniad\\Prif}%
    }{%
      \schema{%
        \schemabox{Syniadau\\Cyflenwol}%
      }{%
        \schemabox{Manylion\\Manylion\\Manylion}%
      }%
    }\\
    \schema{%
      \schemabox{Syniad\\Prif}%
    }{%
      \schema{%
        \schemabox{Syniadau\\Cyflenwol}%
      }{%
        \schemabox{Manylion\\Manylion\\Manylion}%
      }%
    }\\
    \schema{%
      \schemabox{Syniad\\Prif}%
    }{%
      \schema{%
        \schemabox{Syniad\\Cyflenwol}%
      }{%
        \schemabox{Manylion\\Manylion}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: schemata Cymraeg]

If anybody knows what 'schemata' is in Welsh, please leave a comment!

Comment: https://cy.wiktionary.org/wiki/sgema

Comment: @JoeCorneli So there's no way to distinguish `schema` from `schemata`?

Comment: There are plural forms _sgemâu_ and _sgemata_.