# Tikz Mindmap - how to get more nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, trees, mindmaps

```
% Author: Till Tantau
% Source: The PGF/TikZ manual
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{comment}
:Title: Computer science mindmap
:Tags: Manual, Mindmap

Version 1.09 of PGF/TikZ added a library for drawing mindmaps. Here's an example
from the manual. 

| Author: Till Tantau
| Source: The PGF/TikZ manual

\end{comment}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue,text=white]
    node[concept] {Shabda}[clockwise from=0]
child[concept color=green!50!black] {node[concept] {Prathama}[clockwise from=60]
child { node[concept] {Ekvachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Dvivachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Bahuvachana} }
}
child[concept color=red!50!black] {node[concept] {Dvitiya}[clockwise from=15]
child { node[concept] {Ekvachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Dvivachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Bahuvachana} }
}
child[concept color=red!50!black] {node[concept] {Trutiya}[clockwise from=-45]
child { node[concept] {Ekvachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Dvivachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Bahuvachana} }
}
child[concept color=red!50!black] {node[concept] {Chaturthi}[clockwise from=-90]
child { node[concept] {Ekvachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Dvivachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Bahuvachana} }
}
child[concept color=red!50!black] {node[concept] {Panchami}[clockwise from=-90]
child { node[concept] {Ekvachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Dvivachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Bahuvachana} }
}
child[concept color=red!50!black] {node[concept] {Shasthi}[clockwise from=135]
child { node[concept] {Ekvachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Dvivachana} }
      child { node[concept] {Bahuvachana} }
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I got this example from texexample.net and modified it for my needs, however I can not get more than 6 nodes. Is it the upper limit or can I have 8 nodes and 3 child nodes for all them?

Comment: Aku, Welcome! I fixed up your posting a little. put code in code block by indenting with 4 spaces (or select and click the 10101 button), and theres no need to sign-off as your "Badge" appears automagically!

Comment: Another thing: I would recommend submitting minimal examples. so, for example, the comments and comment field are irrelevant to the problem, so you should consider removing them..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More nodes are possible. You could change the `sibling angle`.

Here is an example with 12 child nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue,text=white,
    level 1 concept/.append style=
      {every child/.style={concept color=blue!70},sibling angle=-30}]
      node[concept] {\Huge\bfseries TikZ}[clockwise from=0]
        child foreach \i in {1,...,12} {node[concept]{\LARGE\bfseries\i}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]