# Visualize connectivity of a document's cross referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

Easy management of cross-referencing with `\label` and `\ref` is a very handy basic component of most TeXing.

However, I am wondering if there are any tools out there to visualize the connectivity of a document?

For example, generate a graph where nodes are labelled units (e.g., sections, subsections, figures), and we have an arrow from one node to another if it references it?

Comment: Sounds to me like a concept map of the TeX document. Wonder if that would be possible in TikZ ...? You essentially want to pass the reference information automatically to the created nodes.

Comment: There is [showlabels](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) to show label commands in the margin, but CTAN claim you can do the same thing for other commands as `\ref`.

Comment: Would your question resemble a prestation like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/mind-maps-in-latex)?

Comment: what would be the node for a \ref in the middle of some paragraph in an itemize list on the last page of a longer subsubsection?

Comment: One possible solution is my unpublished [RDFRef package](https://github.com/michal-h21/rdfref). See the answers linked in README. But it is not exactly easy to use, unfortunately.